# "gi" doesn't work in my buffers. No error

Tags: key-bindings, cursor-movement

I recently learned about <kbd>gi</kbd>. It doesn't seem to work in my PHP buffer. I get no error message.

I expect `gi` to go to insert.

I also write with markdown. In this buffer I get an error that says I do not have a language server.

What is the right way to set this up?

Comment: Does it work with `vim --clean`? Does `:map gi` return anything?

Comment: What do you expect from `gi`? 1. The standard Go to Insert position or 2. Go to Implementation? Did you installed an LSP bridge (like [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) or [mason-lspcofig.nvim](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim))?

Comment: Seems OP asks about 2. but my comment aims at 1. Feel free to ignore. Adding expected behavior to a question helps to prevent such misunderstandings.

Comment: I understood gi to be "go back to last point in edit mode"

Comment: So I was right after all. Thank you for your clarifications.

Comment: You were indeed. It wasn't completely clear, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gi` has a standard mapping:

`:help gi`

```
gi          Insert text in the same position as where Insert mode
            was stopped last time in the current buffer.
            This uses the |'^| mark.  It's different from "`^i"
            when the mark is past the end of the line.
            The position is corrected for inserted/deleted lines,
            but NOT for inserted/deleted characters.
            When the |:keepjumps| command modifier is used the |'^|
            mark won't be changed.
```

This one should work on your Vim configuration without specific LSP plugin.

But If you have installed a LSP plugin (e.g. [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)) then depending on your configuration the `gi` can be overridden by a Go to Implementation action.

For that to work you need to install the corresponding LSP server.

For PHP and coc.nvim the Vim command to run is:

```
:CocInstall @yaegassy/coc-intelephense
```

or

```
:CocInstall coc-phpls
```

depending of the LSP server you want to install.

Remark: For `markdown` the Go to Definition action has no obvious meaning to me.

Comment: The key was replaced by an lsp key. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm happy we have solved your problem :-)

Comment: The funny thing is that the plugin correctly exposes `<Plug>` mappings, but also provides [an example config](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim?tab=readme-ov-file#example-vim-configuration) that a) aggressively overrides native commands and b) ends up being copied wholesale by hasty users.